# group_concat issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have this query:

```
SELECT
form.id AS `Form ID`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(IF(questions = 'Area:',answer, NULL)) AS Area,
 GROUP_CONCAT(IF(questions = 'Number of Local Hires:', answer, NULL)) AS `Number of Local Hires`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(IF(questions = 'Dates:', answer, NULL)) AS Dates,
 GROUP_CONCAT(IF(questions = 'Salary Per Local Hire Per Day:', formanswer.answer, NULL)) AS `Salary Per Local Hire Per Day`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(IF(questions = 'Amount:', answer, NULL)) AS Amount
FROM
form
INNER JOIN formquestions ON formquestions.forms_id = form.id
INNER JOIN formanswer ON formanswer.formsquestion_id = formquestions.id
WHERE
form.id = 2 AND
form.id = formquestions.forms_id AND
formanswer.formsquestion_id = formquestions.id
```

The result is correct but I want it in another row. I tried grouping it but still not working.

Here's the output so far.[image: query result]

Tables:
form,formquestions,formanswer in order.

[image: form]
[image: formquestions]
[image: formanswer]

Expected output will be:

```
Form ID | Area | Number of Local Hires | Dates |
2          CBR    ...                    ...  
2          DVO    ...                    ...
```

Comment: Can you show  your expected output ?

Comment: Edited the question. I want the values to show in separate rows.

Comment: expected output is still not very clear.. it would help if you can post a sample table and the output you are getting as well as your expected output

Comment: Nah, I just want the result of the query to be in a separate rows. Like the: `CBR | 4 | 3 | 300 | 1200` in one row and `DVO | 6 | 2 | 100 | 600` in the following row.

Comment: @SachiTekina For your expected output it looks that you really don't need  `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I am following [this](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78) tutorial. I tried `MAX` but it only shows one value.

Comment: @SachiTekina: I agree with khalid.. you probably don't need group by... again, it would help if you can provide sample tables along with expected output